# Convergence of power series at endpoints

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

I´m kinda struggling with figuring out whether or not sum converges or diverges for:

$x_1=\frac14$

$x_2=-\frac14$

For sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{(3+(-1)^n)^n(x)^n}{n}$$

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's study the partial sums $\displaystyle f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^l  \frac{(3+(-1)^n)^nx^n}{n}$.

We have $\displaystyle f(2l) = \sum_{n=1}^{2l}  \frac{(3+(-1)^n)^nx^n}{n}$.

$$f(2l) = \sum_{n=1}^{l}\frac{(3+(-1)^{2n})^{2n}x^{2n}}{{2n}} + \sum_{n=1}^{l}  \frac{(3+(-1)^{2n-1})^{2n-1}x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$$

$$f(2l) = \sum_{n=1}^{l} \left (\frac{4^{2n}x^{2n}}{{2n}} +  \frac{2^{2n-1}x^{2n-1}}{2n-1} \right)$$

Now if $x = \frac{1}{4}$:

$$f(2l) = \sum_{n=1}^{l} \left (\frac{4^{2n}(\frac{1}{4})^{2n}}{{2n}} +  \frac{2^{2n-1}(\frac{1}{4})^{2n-1}}{2n-1} \right)$$

$$f(2l) > \sum_{n=1}^{l} \frac{1}{{2n}} = \frac{1}{2}H_l$$

Since $H_l$ (the $l$th Harmonic number) grows without bound for large $l$, $x = \frac{1}{4}$ diverges.

Now if $x = -\frac{1}{4}$:

$$f(2l) = \sum_{n=1}^{l} \left (\frac{4^{2n}(-\frac{1}{4})^{2n}}{{2n}} +  \frac{2^{2n-1}(-\frac{1}{4})^{2n-1}}{2n-1} \right)$$

$$f(2l) = \sum_{n=1}^{l} \left (\frac{1}{{2n}} -\frac{2^{1-2n}}{2n-1} \right)$$

$$f(2l) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{l} \left (\frac{1}{{n}} -\frac{4}{2^{2n}(2n-1)} \right)$$

$$f(2l) = \frac{1}{2} H_l - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{l} \frac{4}{2^{2n}(2n-1)} $$

The left part diverges, the right part converges, so $f(2l)$ as a whole diverges for $x = -\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: And now, simply determine whether each of the series $$\sum_n\frac1n\qquad \sum_n\frac1{2^{2n}(2n-1)}$$ converges or diverges. Only if they both diverge will you be unable to conclude...

Answer (score 0):

Here I only address the most difficult case, i.e., $x=-1/4$. With $n$ even, consider the sum of the $n$th term and the one behind it: After simplifying, you get
$$ \frac1n-\frac{(1/2)^{n+1}}{n+1}. $$
The sum of the first terms (over all *even* $n$, recallJ diverges, while the sum of the second terms converges. So you get divergence at this point.